# How to convert SQLite DATE field to TDate?

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi

I use this code:

```
DateTimePicker1.Date := SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday').Value;
```

But it gives me an error message:

> Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Double).

I also tried this code:

```
DateTimePicker1.Date := VarToDateTime(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday').Value);
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error message:

> Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Date)

Note: I'm using an SQLite Database. The **data type** of the field "birthday" is DATE.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: This has nothing to do with date time pickers. You need to get a date time from your db. Why did you store the date as a string?

Comment: Have you tried DateTimePicker1.Date := SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday').AsDateTime;

Comment: In addition to the other comments, you should avoid the habit of accessing a database field via its .Value property.  That returns a variant.  Get used to using the ".AsString.", ".AsFloat", "AsDateTime" etc instead.

Comment: a) I seem to recall from your other questions that you use D7.  Is that what you're using for this project?  b) I'm guessing from your component name "SqlQuery1" that you're using Delphi's DBExpress components.  Is that correct.  c)  If the answer to b) is "Yes", are you surfacing your data on your form via a TClientDataSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code actually works fine if the value of **SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday')** is not **NULL**:

```
DateTimePicker1.Date := VarToDateTime(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday').Value);
```

Mr. David Heffman's comment helped me realize that when the **birthday** field (DATE data type) queried with a **NULL** value, it will return an error message that says:

> Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Date).

Therefore, I managed to do this to solve my problem:

```
if not SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday').IsNull then
    DateTimePicker1.Date := VarToDateTime(SQLQuery1.FieldByName('birthday').Value);
```

Comment: Glad you found an answer, but next time please write a better question by including details like the version information I asked for; readers should not have to guess these things.

Comment: @MartynA I'm thankful for all of the things that I learned here in the stackoverflow community. Well, I'm just a hobbyist programmer and I'll take all the great advices from the Masters here.